# Ratner's orbit closure for a unipotent semigroup

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory, topological-dynamics

For Ratner's orbit closure theorem, one may refer to the following [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratner%27s_theorems).

Let $\{u_t\mathrel: t\in \mathbb{R} \}\subset G$ be a unipotent one-parameter subgroup of a connected Lie group. Let $\Gamma$ be a lattice of $G$. From the theorem, we know that the closure of every full orbit $\{x\cdot u_t\mathrel: t\in \mathbb{R}\}$ is dense in the orbit $xS\subset \Gamma\backslash G$ of a certain subgroup $S$ of $G$.

Do we also have the density of the semigroup orbit $\{x\cdot u_t\mathrel: t\geq 0\}$ in certain orbits of subgroups? Is $\{x\cdot u_t\mathrel: t\geq 0\}$ just dense in $xS$ as well?

Comment: I guess, one should look at the proof to see whether it uses negative times.

Comment: An easier special case (with the full Borel group rather than just U) is discussed in Section 2.2 of http://perso.ens-lyon.fr/ghys/articles/dynamiqueflots.pdf . In the cocompact case, density is reduced to density of $\Gamma$ in $G/B$, so one may look at $G/B^+$ and wonder whether density of $\Gamma$ still holds.

Answer (score 2):

$\DeclareMathOperator\supp{supp}$The theorem holds for semigroups as well (well, in the finite volume setting! in the infinite volume setting there are subtleties between two-sided and one-sided averages).

Assume $\mu$ is an $S$-invariant and ergodic probability measure, where $S$ is a semigroup inside a one-parameter unipotent subgroup $U$.
We will show that $\supp(\mu)$ contains a full $U=\langle S\rangle$ orbit, that's enough.
Pick some $x\in \supp(\mu)$.
Consider $\overline{S\cdot x}=P$. For a generic point $x$, $P=\supp(\mu)$ by the ergodic theorem.
Notice that $S\cdot P\subset P$, moreover $S^{2}\cdot P=S\cdot P$, so this is an $S$-invariant subset. By ergodicity $\mu(S\cdot P)=1$, but we also have that $\mu(P)=1$ as well, so $P=S\cdot P$ up to a measure zero set, or in other words $S^{-1}\cdot P=P$ as well, hence $P$ is invariant under $S\cup S^{-1}$, now you may apply the orbit closure theorem.

P.S. you might want to consider the paper by Nimish Shah - "Invariant measures and orbit closures on homogeneous spaces for actions of subgroups generated by unipotent elements" ([MSN](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1699367)) in [Lie groups and ergodic theory](http://hdl.handle.net/2027/mdp.39015053123934), where he discusses the move from Ratner's theorem to discrete subgroup actions!

Comment: I did some light proofreading, which I hope is OK.  One thing that I didn't change is that you refer to a semigroup $S$ inside a unipotent group $U$, and later say $U = \langle S\rangle$.  I think you meant to replace $U$ by the group generated by $S$, but I wasn't sure if this was instead an additional hypothesis.

Comment: @LSpice, thanks, I meant $S$ is the positive semigroup inside $U$, which is a one-parameter unipotent group.

Comment: @LSpice, he meant the full-positive semigroup. Not a discrete one. Dealing with a discrete subgroup/group situation is a bit more complicated (and needs a suspension construction, as in Shah's article I have mentioned).

Comment: I don't think I mentioned discreteness, and I didn't have it in mind, so I'm not sure to what [that](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/365670/ratners-orbit-closure-for-a-unipotent-semigroup/368607#comment930104_368607) is responding (although certainly I believe you that there is more complication involved).  Your [first comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/365670/ratners-orbit-closure-for-a-unipotent-semigroup/368607#comment930103_368607) is what I meant.

Comment: @LSpice, it is clear that for $\mathbb{R}$, the group generated by the positives (or say any non-discrete semigroup) is the whole group.
I suspected that you might have considered a discrete semigroup like $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Since we're on the same page, there's no point fussing about it; but the original language just said that $S$ was a semigroup inside a unipotent group $U$.  This allows, for example, the possibility of $S$ being the semigroup $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & \mathbb R_{> 0} \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$ inside $U = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & * & * \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$, in which case $S$ does not generate $U$.  Your new language clarifies that that's not what you mean, so all is well.